# Something about Singelton

Tags: java, singleton, instance

So we were recently introduced to the Singleton Pattern, and I've found a lot of great uses for it since, but there's just one really small thing that bugs me about it. I've noticed that in every example I've seen for the singleton pattern,the standard getInstance() method looks like this:

```
    private static Singleton instance = null;

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if ( instance == null ) 
        instance = new Singleton();
    return instance;
}
```

The thing I want to know is, is there a point in checking if the instance variable is null?

Would it work if you just assigned the instance variable to a new Singleton instance straight away and just return it like this:

```
    private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
    return instance;
}
```

Sorry if this seems like a waste of time of a question, but I just wanted to know if there was any reason as to why the first example is use everywhere.

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: Forgot to make the methods static.

Comment: Note that if you're really finding "a lot of great uses for it" you're probably overusing it.  The need to use a singleton should be relatively rare, and especially if you find yourself using several in each application you're very likely not designing your apps correctly.

Comment: And it's likely true that there's an overuse of the "lazy" pattern (because folks don't ask themselves the question you're asking).  In probably a majority of cases where a singleton is used it will be inevitably created and deferring the creation has no advantage (and some disadvantages in terms of performance and threading-related bug risks).

Comment: That was more of an answer than I was expecting, but thank you. Also, "a lot of great uses for it" was probably a bit of a stretch, but I get what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are valid ways of creating a Singleton instance. The former is called **lazy initialization** and the latter is called **eager initialization**

Lazy initialization will help if the cost of creation of singleton instance is **high**. In this case the singleton instance is created only when its required.

On the other hand, eager initialization is by default **Thread-safe**

Comment: There is also a use for the "lazy" pattern when the singleton cannot be created when the class is initially loaded, due to the ordering of other activities in the app.

Answer (score 2):

The 1-st example (*lazy load*) is **not thread safe**; to make it **thread safe** you can put it

```
    private static volatile Singleton instance = null;
    private static final Object syncObj = new syncObj();

    public static Singleton getInstance() { // <- do not forget "static"
      // Double checked locking pattern
      if (instance != null) 
        return instance;

      synchronize(syncObj)  {
        if (instance != null) 
          return instance;

        instance = new Singleton();
      }

      return instance;
   }
```

The second example (*eager load*) is **thread safe**:

```
  // "final" looks good here
  private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();

  public static Singleton getInstance() { // <- do not forget "static"
    return instance;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First example is a lazy loading of instance creation where first request to `getInstance` method create the Instance.

To avoid multiple object creation using lazy loading at first time method call (from multiple thread at same time), Object creation must be synchronized.

```
if (null == instance ) {
    synchronized (Singleton.class){
        if (null == instance ) {
            instance = new Singleton();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you only create an instance of the class when you really need it (lazy initialization) the first time. So, you are using less memory until you need the class.

If you have a lot of Singleton, you are saving memory and time if you finally don't need them.